# Cannot find the css selector, method or element error using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
<div class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitMenuItemLabel cpNavLeftLink dijitMenuItemSelected dijitMenuItem" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-dojo-attach-event="onmouseenter:_onHover,onmouseleave:_onUnhover,ondijitclick:_onClick" aria-labelledby="dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2_text" id="dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2" aria-disabled="false" widgetid="dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2" aria-haspopup="true" style="">*
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" id="dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2_text">Carload Tools</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to access the following element using selenium but for some reason it saying that they are not able to recognize this element please help. My code is working fine for other elements but for this one its not able to find the element.

Comment: <div class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitMenuItemLabel cpNavLeftLink dijitMenuItemSelected dijitMenuItem" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-dojo-attach-event="onmouseenter:_onHover,onmouseleave:_onUnhover,ondijitclick:_onClick" aria-labelledby="dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2_text" id="dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2" aria-disabled="false" widgetid="dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2" aria-haspopup="true" style="">
 <span data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" id="dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2_text">Carload Tools</span>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

To identify the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2[widgetid='dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2']>span#dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2_text[data-dojo-attach-point='containerNode']")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2' and @widgetid='dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2']/span[@id='dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2_text' and @data-dojo-attach-point='containerNode']")
  ```

---

Ideally, to locate a ***visible*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2[widgetid='dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2']>span#dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2_text[data-dojo-attach-point='containerNode']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2' and @widgetid='dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2']/span[@id='dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_2_text' and @data-dojo-attach-point='containerNode']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. Thank you for the help though